# Late 90 Honda Civic cooling system hose broke off ,is it safe to drive?

Tags: honda, civic, troubleshooting

One of the cooling system hoses, Freon I believe, broke off. I capped both ends. Is it safe to drive? Also, there's a noise near the front driver side tire, like a rubbing sound. The car decelerates rather quickly after releasing gas pedal? What might be the issue?

Comment: Are you also spelling a burning material smell? If it's a stuck caliper, this is likely the asbestos from the padding on the brakes.

Comment: Just to nitpick, the vast majority of brake pad manufacturers haven't used asbestos in many years, due to its well-documented toxicity. They do have a distinctive smell, though.

Answer (score 6):

The rubbing sound is likely a seized brake caliper.  It is highly likely that the cheapest option will be to have the caliper replaced.

If the car decelerates quickly, like you say, then it is not safe to drive.  The brake and surrounding components will be getting hot.  This could lead to a seized bearing and possible sudden failure.  The heat buildup could also cause the brake fluid to boil, which could then cause a drop in brake performance.

The air conditioning leak should not be a problem, if that really is what it is.